# How to 'Ctrl + C' in Bamboo Spec Plan?

Tags: npm, jestjs, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I'm running `npm run test` in my Bamboo Specs. The test runs fine but after it completes, the job just stops and hangs. Is there a way to 'Ctrl + C' like in command line to exit the jest test?

This is my bamboo yaml:

```
App.test.js:
  tasks:
    - any-task:
        plugin-key: com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-nodejs-plugin:task.builder.npm
        configuration:
          isolatedCache: 'false'
          runtime: Node.js
          command: install
        description: npm install
    - any-task:
        plugin-key: com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-nodejs-plugin:task.builder.npm
        configuration:
          isolatedCache: 'false'
          runtime: Node.js
          command: run test
        description: npm run test
```

Comment: Are you running the tests in watch mode?

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe, thanks for replying. yup, i am running the tests in watch mode

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, I realised I need to do `set CI=true`